# Running main from java .class in MATLAB with accompanying .jar codec file

Tags: java, matlab

I have a main method to run from a java class in Matlab. Some of the methods used in the java class file are in a .jar file.

My javaclasspath.txt looks like this:

```
C:\***\somefolder\commons-codec-1.7.jar
C:\***\somefolder
```

The 'X.class' file is the the 'somefolder' folder, along with its commons-codec-1.7.jar file that it requires to run.

My Matlab Java version is the following :

```
'Java 1.8.0_201-b09 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode'
```

with Environment Variable MATLAB_HOME pointing to:

```
'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\jre'
```

The java .class script was compiled using this SDK.

My MATLAB code is:

---

```
import commons-codec-1.7.*
o = 'X'
javaMethod('main',o,'')
```

---

Which outputs this error:

---

```
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64String([B)Ljava/lang/String;

    at X.main(X.java:28)
```

---

Which from my understanding results from MATLAB failing to find the required methods in 'commonds-codec-1.7.jar'. How to I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.

The solution was to change the javaclasspath.txt to :

```
 <before> C:\***\somefolder\commons-codec-1.7.jar
 C:\***\somefolder
```

This forces commons-codec-1.7.jar to override commons-codec.jar which was in the default static paths of my MATLAB installation.